# printable char in java

Tags: java, unicode, non-printing-characters

Does anyone knows how to detect printable characters in java?

After a while ( trial/error ) I get to this method:

```
    public boolean isPrintableChar( char c ) {
        Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.of( c );
        return (!Character.isISOControl(c)) &&
                c != KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED &&
                block != null &&
                block != Character.UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS;
    }
```

I'm getting the input via KeyListener and come Ctr-'key' printed an square. With this function seems fairly enough.

Am I missing some char here?

Comment: I've never understood why Java does not have a `Character.isPrintable()` method. Another technique is to compare `Character.getType(ch)` with all of the printable Unicode character classes, which still seems like a lot of effort to go to.

Comment: You should consider this, this answer did this for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41100873/5285687

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It seems this was the "Font" independent way.

```
public boolean isPrintableChar( char c ) {
    Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.of( c );
    return (!Character.isISOControl(c)) &&
            c != KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED &&
            block != null &&
            block != Character.UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS;
}
```

Comment: isISOControl returns true for newline characters, which are certainly printable.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not perfectly sure whether I understand your problem. But if you want detect if character can be drawn to Graphics object, and if not print some placeholder char you might find usefull:

```
Font.canDisplay(int)
```

It will check whether font can display specific codepoint (it is more that check whether font is displayable at all -- since there are chars that are displayable - like ą - but some fonts cant display them.

Comment: This worked also. Thank you. I'm printing on a jlabel all the character written in the key board. With out this validation ^c , "RETURN" "ESC" F1..F12 characters are displayed as strange little squares.  Both (my function and your method ) filter them properly. I guess I should add some test case.

Comment: Ok, It worked with the characters in my keyboard, but after iterate from 0 to Character.MAX_VALUE there are a number of chars that cannot be displayed by Font.canDisplay() around char 384. That depends on user font. Both will work. Thank you