# How to detect and replace non-printable characters in a string using Java?

Tags: java, replace, character, non-printable

For instance I have a string like this : abc123[*]xyz[#]098[~]f9e

[*] , [#] and [~] represents 3 different non-printable characters.
How can I replace them with "X" in Java ?

Frank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to strip all non-printable characters from a Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161534/fastest-way-to-strip-all-non-printable-characters-from-a-java-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your questions. If you can formulate it better, I think a simple regular expression replacement may be all that you need.

```
String r = s.replaceAll(REGEX, "X");
```

REGEX depends on what you need:

```
"\\*|#|~"   : matches only '*', "#', and '~'
"[^\\d\\w]" : matches anything that is neither a digit nor a word character
"\\[.\\]"   : matches '[' followed by ANY character followed by ']'
"(?<=\\[).(?=\\])" : matches only the character surrounded by '[' and ']'
```

Answer (score 2):

[This SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220547/printable-char-in-java) shows a way to test, in Java, whether a given character is printable.

As you surely know, in Java you cannot directly alter a string: rather, you make a new [StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object initialized with the string, alter the string builder object (e.g. with `setCharAt` calls where the method above-mentioned shows the character at that index isn't printable), and finally call `toString` on the string builder object to make a new string object, which you can return from your method, or assign to the same identifier you were using to refer to the original string, etc, etc, depending on your exact needs.