# How can non-ASCII characters be removed from a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, char

I have strings `"A função"`, `"Ãugent"` in which I need to replace characters like `ç`, `ã`, and `Ã` with empty strings.

How can I remove those non-ASCII characters from my string?

I have attempted to implement this using the following function, but it is not working properly.  One problem is that the unwanted characters are getting replaced by the space character.

```java
public static String matchAndReplaceNonEnglishChar(String tmpsrcdta) {
    String newsrcdta = null;
    char array[] = Arrays.stringToCharArray(tmpsrcdta);
    if (array == null)
        return newsrcdta;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int nVal = (int) array[i];
        boolean bISO =
                // Is character ISO control
                Character.isISOControl(array[i]);
        boolean bIgnorable =
                // Is Ignorable identifier
                Character.isIdentifierIgnorable(array[i]);
        // Remove tab and other unwanted characters..
        if (nVal == 9 || bISO || bIgnorable)
            array[i] = ' ';
        else if (nVal > 255)
            array[i] = ' ';
    }
    newsrcdta = Arrays.charArrayToString(array);

    return newsrcdta;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to strip all non-printable characters from a Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161534/fastest-way-to-strip-all-non-printable-characters-from-a-java-string)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

This will search and replace all non **ASCII** letters:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
```

Comment: thanks for response.. but this "A" is still not able to replace with empty string.

Comment: @rahulsri A is a perfectly valid ASCII character. Why should it be replaced?

Comment: @Dev i think it is not visible but this is a Latin character whose Unicode value is "\u00c3".

Comment: @rahulsri Can you post this, which cannot be replaced by editing your question please?

Comment: @rahulsri **\u00c3** == `Ã` and yes, it is replaced. You have something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Most likely you want to strip non-printable and control characters, too. In that case you would use the following regexp: `"[^\\x20-\\x7E]"` Or simply: `"[^ -~]"`

Comment: `"[^\\p{ASCII}]"` is an equivalent alternative to `"[^\\x00-\\x7F]"`.

Answer (score 97):

FailedDev's answer is good, but can be improved. If you want to preserve the ascii equivalents, you need to normalize first:

```
String subjectString = "öäü";
subjectString = Normalizer.normalize(subjectString, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");

=> will produce "oau"
```

That way, characters like "öäü" will be mapped to "oau", which at least preserves some information. Without normalization, the resulting String will be blank.

Comment: Your answer is good, but can be improved. Removing the usage of Regex in your code and replacing it with a for loop is incredibly faster (20-40x). More here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15191508/2511884

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The extent of the difference in performance was unexpected.

Comment: You probably want to use Normalizer.Form.NFKD rather than NFD - NFKD will convert things like ligatures into ascii characters (eg ﬁ to fi), NFD will not do this.

Comment: `Normalizer.normalize("ãéío – o áá", Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");`
yields "aeio  o aa" but

`echo "ãéío – o áá" | iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT`
yields "aeio - o aa".

Is there a way to make java replace "–" with "-" like with iconv?

Answer (score 27):

This would be the Unicode solution

```
String s = "A função, Ãugent";
String r = s.replaceAll("\\P{InBasic_Latin}", "");
```

`\p{InBasic_Latin}` is the Unicode block that contains all letters in the Unicode range U+0000..U+007F (see [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#block))

`\P{InBasic_Latin}` is the negated `\p{InBasic_Latin}`

Comment: (Note to anyone confused like me: the uppercase \P is negation.)

Comment: @user1187719, you could be more precise, than "This does not work".   This answer already received some upvotes, so it can not be completely useless. Of course, if you have a Java version before [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html), than I agree. Unicode in regex is not working there.

Comment: @stema - I ran it in Java 6, so your Java 7 theory holds water.

Comment: it removes the special characters and "not" replace them with ASCII equivalent

Comment: @Ali, yes you exactly understood my answer. This is what has been asked for 5 years ago. If it is not what you need, go with Michael Böcklings answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this. Special Characters range for alphabets starts from 192, so you can avoid such characters in the result.

```
String name = "A função";

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(char val : name.toCharArray()) {
    if(val < 192) result.append(val);
}
System.out.println("Result "+result.toString());
```

Comment: Why do you check against 192 and not 128 (what would be the ASCII table)? You are assuming a certain encoding (I think ISO-8859-1), but what if the encoding is ISO-8859-2/3/4/5/7... ? There are letters in those area of the table.

Comment: Yes, It depends upon the number of characters we want to allow as well as the encoding. This is just the example. We can add condition based on required characters and encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the function below for removing non-ascii character from the string.
You will get know internal working.

```java
private static String removeNonASCIIChar(String str) {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    char chars[] = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (0 < chars[i] && chars[i] < 127) {
            buff.append(chars[i]);
        }
    }
    return buff.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***[Updated solution]***

can be used with "Normalize" (Canonical decomposition) and "replaceAll", to replace it with the appropriate characters.

```java
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class NormalizeUtils {

    public static String normalizeASCII(final String string) {
        final String normalize = Normalizer.normalize(string, Form.NFD);

        return Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+")
                      .matcher(normalize)
                      .replaceAll("");
    } ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
String s = "A função";
String stripped = s.replaceAll("\\P{ASCII}", "");
System.out.println(stripped); // Prints "A funo"
```

or

```java
private static final Pattern NON_ASCII_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\P{ASCII}");

public static String matchAndReplaceNonEnglishChar(String tmpsrcdta) {
    return NON_ASCII_PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    matchAndReplaceNonEnglishChar("A função"); // Prints "A funo"
}
```

### Explanation

The method [`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) replaces all instances of a given [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex) with a given replacement string.

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Java has the `"\p{ASCII}"` regular expression construct which matches any ASCII character, and its inverse, `"\P{ASCII}"`, which matches any non-ASCII character.  The matched characters can then be replaced with the empty string, effectively removing them from the resulting string.

```java
String s = "A função";
String stripped = s.replaceAll("\\P{ASCII}", "");
System.out.println(stripped); // Prints "A funo"
```

The full list of valid regex constructs is documented in the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

Note: If you are going to be calling this pattern multiple times within a run, it will be more efficient to use a compiled `Pattern` directly, rather than `String.replaceAll`.  This way the pattern is compiled only once and reused, rather than each time `replaceAll` is called:

```java
public class AsciiStripper {
    private static final Pattern NON_ASCII_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\P{ASCII}");
    
    public static String stripNonAscii(String s) {
        return NON_ASCII_PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table contains 128 codes, with a total of 95 [printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), of which only 52 characters are letters:

- `[0-127]` ASCII codes

  - `[32-126]` printable characters

    - `[48-57]` digits `[0-9]`
    - `[65-90]` uppercase letters `[A-Z]`
    - `[97-122]` lowercase letters `[a-z]`

---

You can use [`String.codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) method to get a stream over `int` values of characters of this string and [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter-java.util.function.IntPredicate-) out *non-ASCII* characters:

```java
String str1 = "A função, Ãugent";

String str2 = str1.codePoints()
        .filter(ch -> ch < 128)
        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(str2); // A funo, ugent
```

Or you can *explicitly* specify character ranges. For example filter out *everything* except letters:

```java
String str3 = str1.codePoints()
        .filter(ch -> ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'
                || ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(str3); // Afunougent
```

---

<sup>See also: [How do I not take Special Characters in my Password Validation (without Regex)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373121/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An easily-readable, ascii-printable, streams solution:

```
String result = str.chars()
    .filter(c -> isAsciiPrintable((char) c))
    .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());

private static boolean isAsciiPrintable(char ch) {
    return ch >= 32 && ch < 127;
}
```

To convert to "_": `.map(c -> isAsciiPrintable((char) c) ? c : '_')`

32 to 127 is equivalent to the regex `[^\\x20-\\x7E]` (from comment on the regex solution)

Source for isAsciiPrintable: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ChecksifthestringcontainsonlyASCIIprintablecharacters.htm

Answer (score 0):

[`CharMatcher.retainFrom`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#retainFrom(java.lang.CharSequence)) can be used, if you're using the [Google Guava](https://guava.dev) library:

```java
String s = "A função";
String stripped = CharMatcher.ascii().retainFrom(s);
System.out.println(stripped); // Prints "A funo"
```