# trim non-ascii characters from string returned by nodejs crypto

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, cryptography, trim

I have successfully decrypted a sensitive data using nodejs crypto library.

The problem is that the decrypted data has a trailing non-ascii characters.

How do I trim that?

My current trim function I below does not do the job.

```
String.prototype.fulltrim = function () {
  return this.replace( /(?:(?:^|\n)\s+|\s+(?:$|\n))/g, '' ).replace( /\s+/g, ' ' );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think following would be suffice.

```
str.replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8519863/1520981), you can use:

```
String.prototype.fulltrim = function () {
  return this.replace( /([^\x00-\xFF]|\s)*$/g, '' );
};
```

This should remove all spaces and non-ascii characters at the end of the string, but leave them in the middle, for example:

```
"Abcde ffאggg ג ב".fulltrim();
// "Abcde ffאggg";
```