# Java problems while working with file

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I've got some problems trying to delete from my string a subsequence `\u000`.

Firstly, I read bytes [] from my file into string by `String str = new String(bytes, "UTF8");` then I get the `str` which equals `\u0004Word` which means `4Word`. `4` is length of word `Word`. So now I need to convert it to regular `4Words`. `replaceAll("\u000", "");`, `replaceALL("\\\\u000", "")` etc doesn't work. How to do that?

```
void FillingStorage() throws Exception{
    Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("db.file"));//that's my file
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    String str = new String(data, "UTF8");
    System.out.println(str);
    String res = str.replaceAll("I don't know what to write here cos nothing I've tried works");
    return;
}
```

UPDATE! 
Firstly, I fill my HashMap with `Key -> Value and Key1 -> Value1`. Then I write it in file as bytes.
So when I try to convert it back to string and print it I see: `Key Value Key1 Value1` instead of `3Key 5Value 4Key1 6Value1`. But suprisingly if you look at string that I print you will see smth like that: `\u0003Key \u0005Value etc...` so looks like that my string contains these numbers but java can't print them.

This is how I write my bytes in file:

```
DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("db.file"), true));
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : storage.entrySet()) {
        byte[] bytesKey = entry.getKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        stream.write((int)bytesKey.length);//it disappears!
        stream.write(bytesKey);
        byte[] bytesVal = entry.getValue().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        stream.write((Integer)bytesVal.length);//disappears too!
        stream.write(bytesVal);
    }
    stream.close();
```

Comment: What you see when you print `str`? I am asking because I doubt that there is `\u000` in it since you claim that `replaceALL("\\\\u000", "")` doesn't work. Or maybe you forgot to store result of `replaceAll` in `str` reference (strings are immutable, so original string is not changed by `replaceAll` method, but new string is created and returned).

Comment: could you paste your replaceAll code line?

Comment: I see ` Words` with 1 space before the word.

Comment: '\u000' is not the same as "\\\\u0000", the former is a single character and the latter is a String with more than a single character in it.

Comment: `'\u000'` is an illegal Unicode escape. There have to be four digits after the `\u`, like `'\u0000'` or `'\u0004'`.

Comment: @DavidConrad yes, there's \u0004.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should use `new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead to avoid the `UnsupportedEncodingException` which can't actually happen with UTF-8.

Comment: do you want to get only the ascii text and remove everything else? you might look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519669/replace-non-ascii-character-from-string

Comment: Can the string be over 127 characters long? If there was an extraneous character `\u0080` or greater at the beginning of the string, it would cause problems interpreting the data as UTF-8. You need to remove the length before you convert it to a string.

Comment: @DavidConrad I get the same string =(

Comment: Of course you get the same string, but the overload of the constructor that takes a `Charset` doesn't throw an `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: @DavidConrad I found out the problem. Question is updated.

Comment: @Debasis Question is updated

Comment: That's weird, you [write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(int)) the length out before the key or the value, and it disappears, but when you read the data back in, there are these weird extra bytes whose values happen to correspond exactly to the lengths of the strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62774/discussion-between-maxim-gotovchits-and-david-conrad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your requirement does not call for regular expressions, so you should have used `replace()` instead.

Second, `\uxxxx` is character literal syntax in Java, so it is not exactly clear that you actually have the characters `\` `u` `0` `0` `0` in your string; it would be much more logical that your byte array simply starts with the single byte equal to 4, which is the string length.

In that case you should simply discard the initial byte from the array when converting to `String`, using the constructor which accepts `offset` and `len` arguments.

If you happen to indeed have all those chars in the string, again simply using `substring` to get rid of the initial 6 characters should be all you need.

Comment: It's no so easy because `bytes` keeps smth like `1A3AAA2AA` so it's pretty difficult to parse it in your way.

Comment: You should then present these difficulties in the question.

Comment: Updated, I've a new problem =(