# Java : Remove strange special characters from String

Tags: java

I want to remove all strange special characters from a string in Java.
Those strange special characters are appearing in form of **?**(Question mark) in MS Word.The image of sample string is given below.

[image]

Comment: Learn about Unicode and UTF-8.

Comment: and check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8519863/2166188

Comment: BTW define *strange*. Do you want to remove all non-ascii characters?

Comment: Those characters not removed by using textToConvert.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")

Comment: Then use: `textToConvert.replaceAll("[\\x00-\\x7F]", "")` I don't see your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
String newString = my_string.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
```

more information about Java Unicode Regular expression [Java Unicode Regular expression here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: I suggest .replaceAll("[!@#$%ˆ&*/\\(\\)\\{\\};:<>/?,.|\\[\\]]", ""); 
it will keep é, á,ç ã for other languages

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
String string = yourString.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
```