# How to escape special characters after sax parser in Java

Tags: java, saxparser

I have used SAX parser to parse a WSDL document. After parsing some special characters like `&#55357;` have been added in the end. How to escape those characters in Java?

Comment: [Escape Characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: What do you mean by special characters *added* in the end? Parsing is a read operation, so nothing is added to the XML. So, added to the end of *what*? --- FYI: � is usually a sign that your reading the XML document using the wrong code page / character set.

Comment: You should replace all non ascii characters  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519669/replace-non-ascii-character-from-string

Comment: Special characters like & # 55357

Comment: In the above post special characters got replaced

Comment: Which character set I should use and how to set the character set

Comment: Please edit your post and show the code you use to read the WSDL.