# Hive : accented characters to their non accented counterparts

Tags: hive, hiveql

How can I replace non-ascii characters with their ascii counterparts in a `SELECT` request sent to hive ? That is have accents removed (`é`, `ê`, `è` => `e`) and have other non alphanumeric characters (``) removed.

I know I can use `regexp_replace()` but I'd have to deal with every accented/non-accented pair there is. Surely, there is something more practical ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to use

```
String subjectString = "öäü";
subjectString = Normalizer.normalize(subjectString, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

As described in
[Replace non ASCII character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519669/replace-non-ascii-character-from-string#answer-17786019)

I have tried using [reflect](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/ReflectUDF) but couldn't make it work due to the `Normalizer.Form` enum parameter.

So, it seems that you have to define a one-line UDF:

```
public class NormalizerUDF extends UDF {
  public String evaluate(String in) {
        return Normalizer.normalize(in, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, do you know how to use this inside a Hive Query?