# Regex in java for control characters both for english and french text

Tags: java

I need to format a string removing the control characters before creating it as an xml. The texts are both in English and French. For eg in words like d?une, I wanted to remove "?" from the text. I tried \p{Cntrl}, [\u0000-\u001f], /[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]/ none of them worked. Could anyone suggest a solution thanks in advance

Comment: Did you really intend to type question marks in the text of this question, or were you trying to type a control character directly?

Answer (score 0):

> This will search and replace all non ASCII letters:
>
> ```
> String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
> ```

Courtesy of FailedDev -> [Replace non ASCII character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519669/replace-non-ascii-character-from-string).

Comment: Thanks  for the suggestion but this will not work in texts like "Isolant de polystyr�ne extrud� rig" where I want to strip of control characters like this.. Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: @JavaLearner What do you mean by 'control characters'?