# How to use id3 plugging in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mp3, id3

Only getting the first letter for every tag, or may be I am wrong somewhere

```
void info() {
MP3Instance mp3instance = new MP3Instance("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Army_320-(Mr-Jat.in).mp3");
    if(mp3instance.parseTagsSync()){
      print(mp3instance.getMetaTags());
      print(mp3instance.metaTags['Title']);
      print(mp3instance.metaTags['Artist']);
      print(mp3instance.metaTags['Album']);
      print(mp3instance.metaTags['Year']);
      print(mp3instance.metaTags['Genre']);
    }
}
```

and here is the output

```
I/flutter ( 6995): {Version: v2.3.0, Title: A
I/flutter ( 6995): A
I/flutter ( 6995): S
I/flutter ( 6995): H
I/flutter ( 6995): 2
I/flutter ( 6995): M
```

Only the first alphabet of text appears and the stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I printed out the ASCII equivalent of `mp3instance.getMetaTags()` and realized that the string has some [ASCII control characters](https://www.ascii-code.com/) in it which terminates the `print()` statement.

After some research I used this method to remove the control characters:

```
String normalizeString(String s) {
    var encoded = ascii.encode(s.toString());
    List<int> normalized = new List.from(encoded.map((e) => (e < 32) ? 32 : e));
    return ascii.decode(normalized);
}
```

I printed the normalized string as follows:

```
 print( "Before normalizing: " + mp3instance.getMetaTags().toString() );
 String normalString = normalizeString( mp3instance.getMetaTags().toString() );
 print( "After normalizing: " + normalString);
 print( "Normalized title: " + mp3instance.metaTags['Title'].toString() );
```

More resources:

[Replace non ASCII character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519669/replace-non-ascii-character-from-string)

[Another id3 tagging flutter library](https://pub.dev/packages/audiotagger)