# Implementation of the Caesar cipher

Tags: java, string, replace, char, caesar-cipher

I have to Implement a static public method named `encodeCaesar` in the class `Functionality.java`, which encodes a text using Caesar encryption and I am a complete novice in Java.

> Signature: `encodeCaesar(String s, int val) : String`
>
> The method gets a string value and an integer value as input parameters. The letters (characters) from the string value are to be shifted by the integer value. For simplicity, I can assume that there are only letters and no spaces, numbers or special characters.
>
> The string value should be converted to lower case before the encryption is performed. The method should return a string where each letter has been moved according to the specified integer value.
>
> Example: `encodeCaesar("Ac",3)` returns `"df"`. If the given integer value is less than 0 or greater than 26, an empty string should be returned.

```java
public class Functionality {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public static String encodeCaesar(String s, int val) {
        char[] newString = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int newChar = newString[i] + val + 26;

            // Handle uppercase letters
            while (Character.isUpperCase(newString[i]) && newChar >= 65 + 26) {
                newChar -= 26;
            }

            // Handle lowecase letters
            while (Character.isLowerCase(newString[i]) && newChar >= 97 + 26) {
                newChar -= 26;
            }

            newString[i] = (char) (newChar);
        }

        return String.valueOf(newString);
    }
}
```

My problem is that in return it give me only true or false. How can I solve this: The method should return a string where each character has been moved according to the specified integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public static String caesar(String s, int val) {
    char[] newString = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int newChar = newString[i] + val + 26;
        // Handle lowercase letters
        while (Character.isLowerCase(newString[i]) && newChar >= 97 + 26) {
            newChar -= 26;
        }
        newString[i] = (char) (newChar);
    }
    return String.valueOf(newString);
}
```

I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet addresses some minor issues:

- non-letter characters (if any) remain unchanged by the cipher
- `while` loop replaced with `if`
- use modulo operator to wrap values over `z`

```java
public static String encodeCaesar(String s, int val) {
    char[] newString = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
        char newChar = newString[i];

        if (newChar >= 'a' && newChar <= 'z') {
            newString[i] = (char) ('a' + (newChar + val - 'a') % 26); 
        }
    }

    return new String(newString); // String.valueOf calls it anyway
}
```

Comparison:

```java
System.out.println("encode: " + encodeCaesar("Viva Caesar! Morituri te salutant!", 3));
System.out.println("caesar: " + caesar("Viva Caesar! Morituri te salutant!", 3));
```

Output:

```
encode: ylyd fdhvdu! prulwxul wh vdoxwdqw!
caesar: ylyd=fdhvdu>=prulwxul=wh=vdoxwdqw>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) method to iterate over `int` values of the characters of this string, and shift them by a given value:

```java
public static String encodeCaesar(String s, int val) {
    if (val < 0 || val > 26) return "";
    return s.codePoints()
            // Stream<Character>
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
            // convert to lowercase
            .map(Character::toLowerCase)
            // filter out non-letters
            .filter(ch -> ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            // if a letter should be shifted
            // outside the alphabetical range,
            // then move it before the beginning
            .map(ch -> ch + val > 'z' ? ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1 : ch)
            // shift letter by a given value
            .map(ch -> ch + val)
            // each character as a single string
            .map(Character::toString)
            // join characters into one string
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(encodeCaesar("Ac", 3)); // df
    System.out.println(encodeCaesar("YZx 32*d", 3)); // bcag
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Replace non ASCII character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375639/14838237)</sup>