# Replacing a character in a string with another character from another string

Tags: java, string, replace, char

I am trying to eventually replace a sentence with another set of String. But I hit a roadblock while trying to replace a char in a String with another character of another String.

Here's what I have so far.

```java
String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String encode = "kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe";
// the sentence that I want to encode
String sentence = "hello, nice to meet you!";

//swapping each char of 'sentence' with the chars in 'encode'
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
    int indexForEncode = letters.indexOf(sentence.charAt(i));
    sentence.replace(sentence.charAt(i), encode.charAt(indexForEncode));
}

System.out.println(sentence);
```

This way of replacing characters doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason

```java
sentence.replace(sentence.charAt(i), encode.charAt(indexForEncode));
```

doesn't work is that `String`s are **immutable** (i.e., they never change).
So, `sentence.replace(...)` doesn't actually change `sentence`; rather, it *returns* a new `String`.  You would need to write `sentence = sentence.replace(...)` to capture that result back in `sentence`.

OK, Strings 101: class dismissed (;->).

Now with all that said, you really don't want want to keep reassigning your partially encoded `sentence` back to itself, because you will, almost certainly, find yourself re-encoding characters of `sentence` that you already encoded.  Best to leave `sentence` in its original form while building up the encoded string one character at a time like this:

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
    int indexForEncode = letters.indexOf(sentence.charAt(i));
    sb.append(indexForEncode != -1
            ? encode.charAt(indexForEncode)
            : sentence.charAt(i)
    );
}
sentence = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! This worked for me. I wish I could upvote. However, is there an article for me to read on if the chars in 'sentence' aren't alphabets? This gives me an error if I have non alphabet characters.

Comment: I've updated the code to address that; maybe you're still looking at the old version.  You might want to  check the [Javadoc for the `indexOf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-): to see the logic behind my fix.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a character array as follows.  Make the changes to a character array and then use [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char%5B%5D)) to get the new version of the string.

```java
String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String encode =  "kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe";
// the sentence that I want to encode
String sentence = "hello, nice to meet you!";

char[] chars = sentence.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    int indexForEncode = letters.indexOf(sentence.charAt(i));
    // if index is < 0, use original character, otherwise, encode.
    chars[i] = indexForEncode < 0 ? chars[i] : encode.charAt(indexForEncode);
}
System.out.println(String.valueOf(chars));
```

Prints

```
xahhi, tbga zi jaaz wiq!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePoints--) method to iterate over the characters of this string and replace them with characters from another string, if any.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNb9swDL3nV7A92YDr7ty0HYaedhg6oLsNOygyHcuVJVeinY@ivz2jHdk1EmeYgcSQxPdIPj6rFK24sTWaMns9HFRVW0dQ8mbakNKpJ4eiSp@s1ijJOr9cLOpmpZUEqYX38EMoA@8L4CfsexLEr9aqDCo@jV7IKbP@/QeEW/s4BHfP8QA0EqHz8ADXYiUzzNeFKl91ZWz95jw17Wa7218vT2FopM2wQ72atRSZ367avChJNdVO79@crTfIqFOYR0MM7YEFam0TMIqXZKFCJNjZ5upSsoxBDmstJD4VwgnZ1R0NjMnQSRLC4zOaDC/ThBQDeGSLpz3sPGGV2obSmglJmwEWL@H2FraiKFQCtFoL2Cueo9jDRr1d/Ysg1HQkuKRIT/CxmJlz6Oy8n3BAuKVkiMqdrcYF2akZOPnGWd6Wqi7QJcxIjTPQGO7Q7Wpi2XwPHCEqh6hjTDWaNRVRDFcPzDou44Gjq2E5zfTd0EvvbLAtOqACoROhtiyJB5vzjvI97DTnhDHtID97SBSPAZMsxxT3oyaPZ0FpJepf9nlVRrKAm0fgl3AxyGKWLwgBchR5ljBwvZ8dBhplMtyOTY5ks@HcHCi2ay9zD3zOmX/i7FPyHIwlqB12n0XSSWvYyaJFUATCd//KJ5fgluPdRnkcDPU/RYaZKLiHL/CVg@Gus0EH@kaRmin2I57M52jH@eEEF9/dtUI3@JzPzkVaIwVfAfzrBLMgwDNI46l5RmZ5vE@jz3s1LdlIHMuuXYaP7eNw@As)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String encode = "kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe";

    String sentence = "hello, nice to meet you!";
    String encoded = replaceCharacters(sentence, letters, encode);
    String decoded = replaceCharacters(encoded, encode, letters);

    System.out.println(encoded); // xahhi, tbga zi jaaz wiq!
    System.out.println(decoded); // hello, nice to meet you!
}
```

```java
public static String replaceCharacters(String text, String from, String to) {
    // wrong cipher, return unencrypted string
    if (from.length() != to.length()) return text;
    // IntStream over the codepoints of this text string
    return text.codePoints()
            // Stream<Character>
            .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
            // encrypt characters
            .map(ch -> {
                // index of this character
                int i = from.indexOf(ch);
                // if not present, then leave it as it is,
                // otherwise replace this character
                return i < 0 ? ch : to.charAt(i);
            }) // Stream<String>
            .map(String::valueOf)
            // concatenate into a single string
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Implementation of the Caesar cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65497616/15402945)</sup>