# How to detect special characters like ^A in a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, special-characters

A file consisting of special characters like ^A is stored in a byte array.how to detect these special characters and remove them?

Comment: The 'special characters' wouldn't happen to include `Â`?

Comment: The word you're looking for is **nonprintable** characters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161534/fastest-way-to-strip-all-non-printable-characters-from-a-java-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java

Comment: You should really try to explain what you've already tried, and show us some code if that is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a fancy encoding all uppercase letters will have values from 65 to 90 and all lowercase letters are between 97 and 122. (See [ASCII Encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/)). All bytes with other values are not letters of the alphabet.

Comment: It's probably more useful in this case to note that the *nonprintable* or *control* characters go from 0-31 in ASCII - for instance, ^A, which is character 1.

Comment: @Kiyura Thanks for pointing it out.I'm looking for a way to get rid of non-printable characters.For the same, now I'm using replaceAll .Code snippet:
    
    String s=new String(buf,"US-ASCII")
    s=s.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]","")
    System.out.println(s)
    
    where buf is the byte array.
    Now when i try to print the truncated string(System.out.println) ,nothing is getting displayed on console.However, if i loop through the string and print each n every character, I'm getting the characters on console.Why so?

Comment: @Manisha, You may be doing something wrong elsewhere in your code. This gist works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/4012570 Notice that if you save it as `Main.java`, compile with `javac Main.java`, and run in a terminal with `java Main`, the control characters are present the first time (the 'o' is backspaced over) and trimmed the second time, and both times the string prints fine.