# empty string checking not working as expected in java

Tags: java

I am trying to check is string empty or not

Simply I have used `apache.lang.StringUtils isNotBlank` method to check

```
String str = " ";
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNotBlank(str)); // Output == true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNotBlank(str.trim())); // Output == true
// But both expected as false
```

But every time its printing `true`.

Some other string its working fine but for above str value above code not working as expected.

Comment: Your string has space.

Comment: You can try removing the whitespaces before checking -
 StringUtils.isNotBlank(str.trim()).

Comment: check if `Character.isWhiteSpace(str.chatAt(0))` returns true or not.

Comment: Have you checked if this is perhaps a non-breaking space or a "hard space", i.e. alt-255? (Created in MS Word with ctrl-shift-space)

Comment: Are you sure about the fully qualified name? Don't you use the newest version, where the name should be `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`. It btw works correctly there.

Comment: Try this `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.getBytes()));` and show us what do you get in your console

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo I am getting output as [-96]

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty that answers your question, you should have got [32], in this case it is considered as a whitespace, a hidden character is in your `str`

Comment: How to replace that character?

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo You may want to write you findings as an answer. `StringUtils.isNotBlank(new String(new byte[]{-96}))` actually returns `true`.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty These questions might help you: 1. [How can I replace non-printable Unicode characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198986/how-can-i-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-in-java) - 2. [Fastest way to strip all non-printable characters from a Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161534/fastest-way-to-strip-all-non-printable-characters-from-a-java-string)

Answer (score 3):

Some characters may appear to be whitespaces, but they aren't, or at least Java doesn't consider them as whitespaces. In your case, when you perform

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.getBytes()));
```

you got `[-96]` as output. -96 is an overflown byte value for 160 which is the [no-breaking space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), but the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.6) doesn't list that character as a whitespace character.
This why `StringUtils.isNotBlank(str)` returns `true`, because your String has non-whitespace characters. `str.trim()` removes whitespaces characters, thus it won't touch the existing no-breaking space.

You can reproduce that by manually creating a String with that character:

```
StringUtils.isNotBlank(new String(new byte[]{-96}));
```

or

```
StringUtils.isNotBlank(new String(new byte[]{(byte) 160}));
```

Both versions will yield `true`.

Comment: I took the liberty to add an explanation about the character in OPs String. Please review my changes :).

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking the length of the string after removing all whitespace:

```
String input = " ";
if (input != null && input.replaceAll("\\s+", "").length() > 0) {
    System.out.println("Not empty.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Empty");
}
```

I offer this an alternative to using the `Apache` library.  The logic is that a non empty string is any string which is not `null` and which has at least one non whitespace character in it.