# Detecting non-printable characters in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have not come across any documentation on this.

Is there a way to find out if a string consists of any non-printable characters in Scala?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485636/how-to-detect-and-replace-non-printable-characters-in-a-string-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method detects [non-printable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters).  A simple Regex pattern is used to look for any characters outside of the `0x20-0x7E` ASCII range:

```
def hasNonprintableAsciiChar(s: String): Boolean = {
  val pattern = """[^\x20-\x7E]+""".r
  pattern.findFirstMatchIn(s) match {
    case Some(_) => true
    case None => false
  }
}

hasNonprintableAsciiChar("abc-xyz-123")
// res1: Boolean = false

hasNonprintableAsciiChar("abc¥xyz£123")
// res2: Boolean = true

hasNonprintableAsciiChar("abc123" + '\u200B')
// res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Unicode has many other non-printable characters. for example http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm

Comment: The suggested method considers anything outside of the printable ASCII char range non-printable hence should be able to detect non-printable Unicode characters.  e.g. `hasNonprintableAsciiChar("abc123" + 0x200B.toChar)` would return `true`.

Comment: thankyou very much for all the responses provided, they are all help ful

Answer (score 2):

Here's the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220547/printable-char-in-java), translated into idiomatic Scala.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent

def isPrintableChar(c: Char) =
  !Character.isISOControl(c) &&
  c != KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED &&
  Option(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c)).fold(false)(
    _ ne Character.UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS)
```