# Check if custom font can display character

Tags: android, typeface, custom-font

I have a custom font which is displaying the box character. The font I am using does not support all languages apparently. I want to check if the String I am about to display can be displayed by my custom font. If it cannot then I want to use the standard Android font (which I know can display the characters). I can't find a method to check if my Typeface can display a particular String though. I am sure I have seen a method around that does this somewhere. Anyone know?

Comment: Hmmmm... I don't think we have enough low-level font access to determine whether a particular glyph exists in a particular font file from within Android.

Comment: bahpo's answer did it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41100873/5285687

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** 
If you're coding for API level 23 or above please use [Paint.hasGlyph()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#hasGlyph(java.lang.String)) as mentioned in the [answer by Orson Baines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36995780/1730966). Otherwise see my original answer below.

---

As you mentioned in your own answer there is no built in methods available for checking this. However if you have some control over what string/characters you want to check, it is actually possible to do this with a slightly more creative approach.

You could draw a character that you know are missing in the font you want to check and then draw a character that you want to know if it exists, and then finally compare them and see if they look the same.

Here is a code sample that illustrates how I implemented this check:

```
public Bitmap drawBitmap(String text){
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(BITMAP_WIDTH, BITMAP_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.drawText(text, 0, BITMAP_HEIGHT / 2, paint);
    return b;
}

public byte[] getPixels(Bitmap b) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(b.getByteCount());
    b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    return buffer.array();
}
public boolean isCharacterMissingInFont(String ch) {
    String missingCharacter = "\u0978"; // reserved code point in the devanagari block (should not exist).
    byte[] b1 = getPixels(drawBitmap(ch));
    byte[] b2 = getPixels(drawBitmap(missingCharacter));
    return Arrays.equals(b1, b2);
}
```

There are some important limitations to keep in mind with this method:

- The character you check (argument to `isCharacterMissing`) must be non whitespace (can be detected by using [Character.isWhitespace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28int%29)). In some fonts missing characters are rendered as whitespace, so if you would compare a whitespace character that exists it would incorrectly be reported as a missing character in fonts like these.
- The `missingCharacter` member must be a character that is known to be missing in the font to be checked. The code point [U+0978](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0978/index.htm) that I am using is a reserved code point in the middle of the Devanagari Unicode block so it should currently be missing in all Unicode compatible fonts, however in the future when new characters are added to Unicode this code point might be assigned to a real character. So this approach is not future proof, but if you supply the font yourself you can make sure you are using a missing character whenever you change the font of your application.
- Since this check is done by drawing bitmaps and comparing them it's not very efficient so it should only be used to check a few characters and not all strings in your application.

**Update:**

The solution to look at U+0978 did not work long as pointed out by others. That character was added in the [Unicode 7.0](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-7.0/) release in [June 2014](http://blog.unicode.org/2014/06/announcing-unicode-standard-version-70.html). Another option is to use a glyph that exists in unicode but that is very unlikely to be used in a normal font.

[U+124AB](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/124ab/index.htm) in the [Early Dynastic Cuneiform](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U12480.pdf) block is probably something that doesn't exist in many fonts at all.

Comment: stock Nexus 4 has a glyph for "\u0978". Instead,  "\u2936" seem to be still missing.

Comment: What should I use for `BITMAP_WIDTH`?

Comment: Anything large enough that each character is drawn differently. For example if you try to draw different letters using just 2x2 pixels many different letters will probably look the same. I think I might have used something like 16 or 20.

Answer (score 8):

As of Android version 23, You can test it like this:

```
Typeface typeface;
//initialize the custom font here

//enter the character to test
String charToTest="\u0978";
Paint paint=new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(typeface);
boolean hasGlyph=paint.hasGlyph(charToTest);
```

Comment: From the JavaDoc: "Checking is done on the entire fallback chain, not just the immediate font referenced." So if you only want to know if it's in the Typeface you specified, this won't work.

Comment: For checking this exact font file with fallback, try [CustomFallbackBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.CustomFallbackBuilder) . API29+.

Answer (score 3):

@nibarius answer works well, though with a different character: "\u2936".

However, that solution is heavy in memory, cpu and time.
I needed a solution for a very small number of characters so I implemented 
a "quick and dirty" solution by checking only the bounds. It works about 50x times faster, so it is more suitable for my case:

```
public boolean isCharGlyphAvailable(char... c) {
      Rect missingCharBounds = new Rect();
      char missingCharacter = '\u2936';
      paint.getTextBounds(c, 0, 1, missingCharBounds); // takes array as argument, but I need only one char.
      Rect testCharsBounds = new Rect();
      paint.getTextBounds(c, 0, 1, testCharsBounds);
      return !testCharsBounds.equals(missingCharBounds);
}
```

I should warn that this method is less accurate than @nibarius, and there are some false negatives and false positives, but if you just need to test a few characters in order to be able to fallback to other characters - this solution is great.

Answer (score 3):

please check the source code from [Googles Mozc](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/afb03ddfe72dde4cf2409863a3bfea160f7a66d8/src/android/src/com/google/android/inputmethod/japanese/emoji/EmojiRenderableChecker.java) project. The EmojiRenderableChecker class seems to work pretty well!

it's like a compat version for [Paint.hasGlypgh](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#hasGlyph(java.lang.String)) (added in Marshmallow).

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who would still like your app to be compatible with APIs less than 23 and still use the hasGlyph function in your code, you can use the @TargetApi(23) in the following way:

```
@TargetApi(23)
public boolean isPrintable( String c ) {
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    boolean hasGlyph=true;
    hasGlyph=paint.hasGlyph(c);
    return hasGlyph;
}
```

And then in your code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if(isPrintable(yourString)) {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

The only problem is that in APIs lower than 23, your app may show blank symbols. But at least in API23+ your app will be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether the music symbol ♫ is being displayed in a string (if it is not being displayed on some devices), you can try [measuring](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) the string width; `if width == 0` then the symbol is absent.

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
Rect rtt = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds( "♫", 0, 1, rtt );
    if( rtt.width() == 0 ){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`PaintCompat.hasGlyph`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/graphics/PaintCompat#hasGlyph(android.graphics.Paint,%20java.lang.String)) which relies on `Paint.hasGlyph` in API version 23 and above, but has a backwards-compatible implementation for older Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this for an app I'm writing that works on API 19.  I am looking through a Japanese Kanji app and supports several different fonts.  I use the Kotlin extension function below.  Note that [toCodepointStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799135/kotlin-split-utf-string-into-single-length-sub-strings-using-codepoint) is a simple function that splits a string based on its codepoints so it's font-independent.

```
private fun String.charsExistInFont(
        typeFace: Typeface): Boolean {
    val chars: Array<String> = this.toCodepointStrings()
    val p = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    p.typeface = typeFace
    val chk = chars.firstOrNull() {
        val r = Rect()
        p.getTextBounds(it, 0, 1, r)
        Log.d(TAG, "char width = ${r.width()}")
        r.width() == 0 && it != " " // rect is 0 width for space.
    }
    return chk == null
}
```