# Is there any unicode character whose glyph is missing in all fonts?

Tags: android, unicode, fonts

On Android, I want to be able to detect if the font used can display a certain character or not, but as I understand it this is not possible with conventional means as indicated by [Check if custom font can display character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815458/check-if-custom-font-can-display-character)

To detect this I'm writing the character I want to check to a bitmap and then I write another character that I know is missing to another bitmap and compare the content of the bitmaps. If they are equal the character is missing.

The question is, **is there any unicode character whose glyph is (more or less) guaranteed to be missing on fonts typically used on Android phones?**

The [Unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character) sounds promising when reading about it on Wikipedia:

> It is used to indicate problems when a system is not able to render a
> stream of data to a correct symbol. It is most commonly seen when a
> font does not contain a character, but is also seen when the data is
> invalid and does not match any character

However after doing a bit of testing I see that this character is not used to represent missing glyphs on either my Windows 7 computer or the Android phone I've tested with (Motorola Atrix).

Comment: Unicode contains a repertoire of more than 110,000 characters and has a limit of 1,114,112 code points. So in the unlikely case that a font has all glyphs (supports all writing systems, all languages), only 10% of the available code points are used. The rest is empty. What if you render whitespace glyph? Do you now about the 'missing character glyph'?

Comment: I wasn't aware of 'missing character glyph', some Googling suggests that U+0000 can/should be used for missing characters in the font. However in at least one font I've tested with U+0000 is rendered as whitespace while missing characters are rendered as squares (similar to U+25A1). I guess my best bet is to use some reserved/unassigned unicode character instead.

Comment: U+0000 is usually used to mark the end of a string. You need .notdef, unicode value undefined: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/recom.htm Characters are assigned in blocks of the same kind. Most blocks have some unassigned points at the end to start the next block on a round number. These points allow Unicode Consortium to add new glyphs to a block. New glyphs don't come into existence often. See http://typophile.com/node/102205. Maybe you can ask your question in the Typophile forum. They can tell you more about how this exactly works and how to render .notdef

Comment: Thanks for the "Recommendations for OpenType Fonts" link, that was useful for me. It seems like I confused the glyph id 0 with unicode code point U+0000. For what I'm trying to do using one of the reserved code points should be good enough (see my own answer).

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Slightly different reason for wanting to detect missing glyphs (automatic detection vs manual detection by the user), but the actual question is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any designated Unicode value for the glyph that is used to render glyphs that are missing in the font used. In the actual font, glyph id 0 should always be the [.notdef glyph](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/recom.htm) which is used for all characters that are missing a glyph. However it is not possible this information from the fonts on Android, so it's not possible to use the .notdef glyph directly.

In Unicode there are many reserved/unassigned code points and my limited testing indicate that these code points are rendered using the .notdef glyph. So by using [U+0978](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0978/index.htm), which is a reserved code point in the middle of the [Devanagari block](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf), I can detect if some other valid, known character exists in the font I want to test.

This is not a future proof solution since new glyphs may be added to reserved code points by the Unicode Consortium in the future. But for my needs it's good enough since what I want to do is a temporary thing that is not relevant any more in the near future.

**Update:**

The solution to look at U+0978 did not work long. That character was added in the [Unicode 7.0](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-7.0/) release in [June 2014](http://blog.unicode.org/2014/06/announcing-unicode-standard-version-70.html). Another option is to use a glyph that exists in unicode but that is very unlikely to be used in a normal font.

[U+124AB](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/124ab/index.htm) in the [Early Dynastic Cuneiform](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U12480.pdf) block is probably something that doesn't exist in many fonts at all.

Comment: Technically, U+25A1 is a popular choice since it has the comment "may be used to represent a missing ideograph" -- Alternatively U+20DE is also used.  This comes directly from the current Unicode specifications: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf

Comment: That's useful to know. However it couldn't be used in my particular case since they only "may" be used for that purpose. In for example the Roboto font both U+25A1 and U+20DE is missing a glyph.

Comment: "Another option is to use a glyph that exists in unicode but that is very unlikely to be used in a normal font." - May not work with Noto (which tries to provide glyphs for every character in Unicode).  However, you could probably use a private use area code point.  There are a ton of those and Unicode will never encode "real" characters there.