# How to detect and replace unsupported emoji?

Tags: android, emoji

There is a chat software that is supported on Android versions ranging from 4.0 to 6.0. iOS is supported too. Recently we've introduced option to use system emojis. However, when someone with latest Android, or iOS, sends message containing latest emoji, the older device can't display it properly. 
Is there a way to detect those emojis that can't be displayed? We want to replace those with some symbol (eg. an empty box or exclamation mark)

Comment: Maybe this may help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36995780/4271923  (plus the other answer with boundary boxes check sound good to me, at least as long as emoji have distinctly different bboxes to the "missing glyph" square).

Answer (score 2):

Get the system stock emojis [Emojis - Unicode - Bytes](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#note1).

Then search the recieved message, if you found some code that it's in your android version emojis diplay it, if not add the symbol you want.

Following the comments you can test it with this

```
Typeface typeface;
//initialize the custom font here

//enter the character to test
String charToTest="\u0978";
Paint paint=new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(typeface);
boolean hasGlyph=paint.hasGlyph(charToTest);
```

Answer (score 1):

please check the source code from [Googles Mozc](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/android/src/com/google/android/inputmethod/japanese/emoji/EmojiRenderableChecker.java) project. The EmojiRenderableChecker class seems to work pretty well!

it's like a compat version for [Paint.hasGlypgh](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#hasGlyph(java.lang.String)) (added in Marshmallow).