# Unicode character not same size as text in TextView

Tags: android, html, kotlin, unicode, textview

I'm trying to show an arrow unicode symbol within a `TextView` but for some reason, the charcter doesn't match the size of the text desite using the `Html.fromHtml` code. Is there something that can be done to fix this?

[image]

**Activity layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity class**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mTV = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTV)

        mTV.text = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.app_name) + " \u2192 " + getString(R.string.app_name), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    }
}
```

Comment: [Why is TextView showing the unicode right arrow (\u2192) at the bottom line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49315570/3290339)

Comment: @Onik This doesn't work doesn't when trying to do the same thing on multiple lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roboto (the system font) [doesn't have arrow glyphs](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?preview.text=&preview.text_type=custom#glyphs), so what you're seeing there is some kind of uh-oh fallback, which you don't seem to be able to style (including through styling tags in your HTML string). So what you can do instead, is stick an `<img>` tag in there, using an `ImageGetter` to provide it with a drawable

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mTV = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTV)
        val appName = getString(R.string.app_name)
        val template = "$appName <img src=\"arrow\"/> $appName"
        mTV.text = Html.fromHtml(template, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT, imageGetter, null)
    }

    private val imageGetter = Html.ImageGetter { name ->
        val resId = when (name) {
            "arrow" -> R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_right_alt_24
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("what the heck is $name")
        }

        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, resId, theme)?.apply {
            // size the arrow here - we need to scale it with the font size,
            // so set its width and height in the XML to sp units
            setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

So this is basically using taking the value of the `src` attribute in the `img` tag and passing it to `imageGetter`, which is just doing a simple mapping to drawable resource IDs.

Then it loads and sizes the drawable - which needs to be scaled to the equivalent `sp` value, so it scales with the text size. It's easiest to just set that in the drawable, and you can tweak the values to get it sized nicely relatively to the text:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="28sp"
    android:height="28sp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorOnSurface">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M16.01,11H4v2h12.01v3L20,12l-3.99,-4z"/>
</vector>
```

This is just the `baseline_arrow_right` drawable you can get from the Vector Assets thing in Resource Manager. Note the `width` and `height` are in **sp** not **dp**, otherwise it wouldn't scale with the system font size.

Also you'll need to make sure it's themed properly, I set the colour to `colorOnSurface` but you'll have work that out for yourself! There's `?android:attr/textColor` but you might have to set the image as `enabled` for it to look right

[image: what the fixed version looks like]

Comment: To clarify, what would happen if `android:fillColor="@android:color/white"` wasn't there?

Comment: As far as I know, it just defines the path as having a fill, so it's a solid shape - there's a ``strokeColor`` one too, if you have neither it probably doesn't display, because there's nothing being drawn with the path. But that's just how the XML looks when you import a vector asset, I just changed the tint and dimensions