# kotlin split utf string into single length sub strings using codepoint

Tags: unicode, kotlin, codepoint

I'm just starting kotlin so I'm sure there is an easy way to do this but I don't see it.  I want to split a into single-length sub strings using codepoints.  In Java 8, this works:

```
public class UtfSplit {
    static String [] utf8Split (String str) {
        int [] codepoints = str.codePoints().toArray();
        String [] rv = new String[codepoints.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < codepoints.length; i++)
            rv[i] = new String(codepoints, i, 1);
        return rv;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String test = "こんにちは皆さん";
        System.out.println("Test string:" + test);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Result:");
        for(String s : utf8Split(test))
            sb.append(s).append(", ");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Test string:こんにちは皆さん
Result:こ, ん, に, ち, は, 皆, さ, ん,
```

How would I do this in kotlin??  I can get to codepoints although it's clumsy and I'm sure I'm doing it wrong.  But I can't get from the codepoints back to a strings.  The whole string/character interface seems different to me and I'm just not getting it.

Thanks
Steve S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same runtime as Java so the code is basically doing the same thing.  However, the Kotlin version is shorter, and also has no need for a class, although you could group utility methods into an object.  Here is the version using top-level functions:

```
fun splitByCodePoint(str: String): Array<String> {
    val codepoints = str.codePoints().toArray()
    return Array(codepoints.size) { index ->
        String(codepoints, index, 1)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val input = "こんにちは皆さん"
    val result = splitByCodePoint(input)

    println("Test string: ${input}")
    println("Result:      ${result.joinToString(", ")}")
}
```

Output:

> Test string: こんにちは皆さん
>
> Result: こ, ん, に, ち, は, 皆, さ, ん

Note:  I renamed the function because the encoding doesn't really matter since you are just splitting by Codepoints.

Some might write this without the local variable:

```
fun splitByCodePoint(str: String): Array<String> {
    return str.codePoints().toArray().let { codepoints ->
        Array(codepoints.size) { index -> String(codepoints, index, 1) }
    }
}
```

See also:

- Kotlin stdlib [Array initializer](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html) by index w/lambda
- Kotlin stdlib [let](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) function

Comment: I'm still too green -- too much magic.  Could you explain what's going on in the last line after the return please?  index ->... is a lambda, right?  Where is the itteration happening?

Comment: @stevensmith Kotlin has an `Array` initializer to construct an array that takes a lambda that receives the index of the item for which is being set (the index into the array).  The lambda returns the value to go into that position.  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html

Comment: I used that to avoid having an array with possible null values, otherwise you would wrestle with having an array of `Array<String?>` when you want `Array<String>`

Comment: You should read all of the stdlib docs, they aren't too large, but you won't get far not knowing the key piece of Kotlin programming.  Take a look, a lot of good stuff in there!

Comment: OK. Next stupid java-type question.  I just plugged in the code and the IDE is complaining "can't find or load class..."  Makes perfect sense but where do you put the code if not in a class?  Learning curve.... Augh!  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: This code just goes into a Kotlin file.  If you have further questions, you'll need to do some research, learn more, or ask other questions.  The code above is my complete file `CodepointSplitExample.kt` (minus a package statement) which I ran as class `CodepointSplitExampleKT` which is covered here in Stack Overflow in questions about how to run a top-level Kotlin `main()`.  Also in Kotlin 1.3 you do not need any args to the `main()`

Comment: @jason-minard, just wanted to say thanks especially for the second code example and reminding me of the Java/Kotlin interoprability.  I couldn't find the codepoints() or the string from codepoint in Kotlin docs and had completely forgotten the interoperability.  I could follow the second example and that will eventually take me through the first.