# Android: Test if a character is displayable/supported?

Tags: android, fonts, character-encoding

I am using Asian characters in my android app, I learned already that some characters are not displayable because they are not supported by the system's fonts. I query a database with Asian characters and I often retrieve signs which are not displayable. These cases are usually not a problem for my application, but are irritating to the user if I display not supported characters.
Is there something like a test of a sign for displayability in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be helpful

```
public boolean isPrintable( char c ) {
    Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.of( c );
    return (!Character.isISOControl(c)) &&
                    block != null &&
                    block != Character.UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS;
}
```

Please refer [printable char in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220547/printable-char-in-java)

Comment: Not working for me. The `KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED` is not available. I used `KeyEvent.UNKNOWN` instead. But its still not working.