# How would you check if a char in Java is typeable?

Tags: java, text, unicode, char

The title pretty much says it all, how would I check if a char is typeable in java?
And what I mean by typeable is not only if it is a letter or digit, but also if it is an exclamation mark or blankspace etc.

I do not want things such as escape and backspace characters to go through the filter.

I am aware of `Character.isLetter()` but this is not what I want, the result is too narrow.

Of course I could use a blacklist / whitelist filter, but since this is rather inconvenient I would prefer a somewhat more practical solution if their is one.

Comment: That's completely dependent on the keyboard layout.

Comment: Even symbols? (exclamation marks, quotation marks etc.)

Comment: At least in part. The inverted question & exclamation marks (¿¡) are easily available on some keyboards, but less so on others. There may be others, but those came first to my mind. On the other hand, if you just want *printable* characters, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220547/printable-char-in-java) question may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of the `Character.isISOControl` methods, if it's a control character then it's *not* typeable in the sense that I think you mean.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character):

> In computing and telecommunication, a control character or non-printing character is a code point (a number) in a character set, that does not represent a written symbol.

Comment: This one did the trick, thanks for all the other answers though!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do this is to use regular expressions. You can exactly specify which characters are "typeable".

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Seriously? ;)

Comment: No, but on the other hand, the question is a little crooked.

Comment: Regex is an answer to everything... almost.

Answer (score 0):

From the String point of view, thinking for instance a char as a single character string, you can use a regex (with a character class) to define what you consider as a valid character.

For instance, you can have something like this:

```
assertTrue("a".matches("[\\w!?/-]")); // Bear in mind that \w is [a-zA-Z0-9]
assertTrue("!".matches("[\\w!?/-]"));
assertTrue("?".matches("[\\w!?/-]"));
assertFalse(":".matches("[\\w!?/-]"));
```

So, you can define within the regex character class what the valid characters are. A more detailed example can be:

```
String charToTest = "W";
String validCharsRegex = "^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*)(-]$"; // Put withing [...] what
                                                     //  you consider valid characters

if (charToTest.matches(validCharsRegex))
    System.out.println("Valid character");
else
    System.out.println("Invalid character");
```

You can define your valid characters in a **[regex character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)** by putting all characters within `[` and `]`. So, for the above example the regex diagram looks like this:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange question because you don't know from which keyboard the ***char*** comes from at the moment you have it.

If you want to check the nature of the ***char*** you could use regular expressions:

```
char a = 'a';
String.valueOf(a).matches(".*"); // returns true
```

Find out more about regular expressions in [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Now if you want to check for **key press events**, you need to tell us which API or framework you are using, or what kind of application you are trying to build, as it would vary how you can check for these events.