# How to check a pressed key is printable or not?

Tags: java, awt, keyevent

How can I check whether a pressed key is printable or not in a key press event in java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220547/printable-char-in-java).

```
   public boolean isPrintableChar( char c ) {
        Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.of( c );
        return (!Character.isISOControl(c)) &&
                c != KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED &&
                block != null &&
                block != Character.UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS;
    }
```