# Removing an extra line separator

Tags: java

For my project I am constantly failing my JUnit test. I think it's due to this extra line that keeps appearing at the end of my code.

It should look like this:
[The expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JASa7.png)

But mine shows this:
[My results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C27yp.png)

I originally had `('\n')`, but I removed it.

```
public static String getRectangle(int maxRows, int maxCols, char symbol) {
    if (maxRows < 1 || maxCols < 1 ) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder rectangle = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxCols; j++) {
            rectangle.append(symbol);
        }
        rectangle.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return rectangle.toString();
}
```

This is the code I've made for this part of my project. All the others are failing for the same reason, but if I am able to figure this one out, then I'll be able to fix the rest.

Comment: Well, then you have to test whether it's the last line you're writing, if yes, the don't append the newline.

Comment: To track this down, run the JUnit test, in the _JUnit_ view double-click on the failure (the first item in the _Failure Trace_) and in the _Result Comparison_ window right-click and select _Show Whitespace Characters_. On Windows `System.lineSeparator()` is `"\r\n"`, not `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to remove the final line separator from the string returned by method `getRectangle`.

One way – that minimizes the required changes to your code – is to simply remove the final line separator before returning the value. Again, there are several ways to do this, for example:

```java
rectangle.substring(0, rectangle.lastIndexOf(System.lineSeparator()))
```

Refer to the *javadoc* for class [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Here is method `getRectangle` with the above change.

```java
public static String getRectangle(int maxRows, int maxCols, char symbol) {
    if (maxRows < 1 || maxCols < 1) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder rectangle = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxCols; j++) {
            rectangle.append(symbol);
        }
        rectangle.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return rectangle.substring(0, rectangle.lastIndexOf(System.lineSeparator()));
}
```

Alternatively, you can change the logic of your nested `for` loops. Instead of appending a line separator, prepend it for every line except for the first line, as demonstrated in the below `getOblong` method.

```java
public static String getOblong(int maxRows, int maxCols, char symbol) {
    boolean first = true;
    StringBuilder rectangle = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        }
        else {
            rectangle.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < maxCols; j++) {
            rectangle.append(symbol);
        }
    }
    return rectangle.toString();
}
```

Actually, you don't need to use loops as there are already API methods that achieve the same result, as demonstrated in the below `getRect` method:

```java
public static String getRect(int rows, int cols, char symbol) {
    String s = String.valueOf(symbol);
    String line = s.repeat(cols);
    String[] lines = new String[rows];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(lines, line);
    return String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines);
}
```

Again, refer to *javadoc* for class [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).

By the way, since you are already checking validity of parameters `maxRows` and `maxCols`, in your `getRectangle` method, shouldn't you also check whether `symbol` is a [printable character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220547/printable-char-in-java)?